# How To Append a Node group from another Blend file Using Python Script

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, shaders, append

How To Append a Node group from another Blend file that is Present in my D drive on my windows computer.
I wan't to Append a Material and path to my material is - 
- D:\2.8\Test01.blend\Material\Test_Material
using a python script.

Can Anyone Help me Out ?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/92676/442

Comment: This Script which you suggested is not loading my file path it is showing error - (Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rakesh\Desktop\Script.blend\Text", line 16, in <module>
OSError: load: C:\Users\Rakesh\Desktop\Fire Shader Advanced.blend\Material failed to open blend file
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console)

Comment: Also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/139322

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got the answer of this problem
this scipt worked for me
 - [image: I got this from somewhere on internet]

```
import bpy
path = "/Users/Rakesh\Desktop/wallpapers/FIRE SHADER/Fire Shader Advanced.blend\\Material\\"
material_name = "domain"
bpy.ops.wm.append( filename = material_name, directory = path)
```

Comment: Could you please post your code?

Comment: I just Made a New Material and Imported it using this script - import bpy
path = "/Users/Rakesh\Desktop/wallpapers/FIRE SHADER/Fire Shader Advanced.blend\\Material\\"
material_name = "domain"
bpy.ops.wm.append(filename=material_name,directory=path)